# Python List Indexes

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a dual list and I am wondering what it the best way to get the indexes of the zeros in the array

```
board =[[1,2,0],
    [2,1,2],
    [1,1,0]]

for boxes in board:
    if 0 in boxes:
        print boxes
```

like this but instead I want to have return 
[0,2]
[2,2]

Comment: What if there's more than one 0 in the sublist?

Comment: if `board` were a NumPy array, you could use `zip(*numpy.where(a == 0))`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Does this matter here? I'm not sure, but I think he's always printing the whole `boxes`... so I think there could also be 3 zeros in, but it would still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
[(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3) if board[i][j] == 0]
```

This will include multiple zeros per row if present.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very vague (what about multiple zeroes in one of the inner lists), feel free to comment if you are looking for something else:

```
zeroes = []
for x, box in enumerate(board):
    if 0 in box:
        zeroes.append((x, box.index(0)))
print zeroes
```

With your given lists, this prints

```
[(0, 2), (2, 2)]
```

A shorter, more pythonic version would be using a list comprehension like this:

```
zeroes = [(x, box.index(0)) for x, box in enumerate(board) if 0 in box]
```

Comment: I did not know about the enumerate function that will diffidently come in handy.   

Is there a way to condense the for if loop in to one line?

Comment: @GeneralZero: This can be written in one line as `zeroes = [(x, box.index(0)) for x, box in enumerate(box) if 0 in box]`.  Note that this code (as well as the code in the above answer) will at most include one zero per row -- not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank you for pointing that out. I in fact do need more than one per row